# QGIS plugin - Works on PC, not on Mac

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I'm adding some functionality to an existing QGIS plugin (EcoValuator from Key-Log Economics). After playing with the existing version of the plugin, it works on a PC, but not on a Mac. The issue is with a step in the code which calculates values in an attribute table.

Before diving too deeply into the code, is there a reason why the plugin would work on PC but not on Mac?  What are some things I should look for?

I was unable to find mention of this on StackOverflow, QGIS documentation, or elsewhere.

Comment: Plugins are compiled and added to the plugin repository. It's possible that the developer of the plugin only compiled a windows version.

Comment: I would use the plugins issue tracker to try and get additional help. https://github.com/Key-Log-Economics/eco-valuator/issues

Comment: @enolan can you say a little more about that?  Where can I learn more about how to compile a version for Mac?

Comment: You would need to get ahold of the plugin code base. Then find the compiling tools for a mac. I don't know the toolset for a MAC.